# Proper Adobe Flash setup

Tags: 12.04, flash, downloads

When prompted to select a download of Adobe Flash for my 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 system, I am given 4 choices.  Which is the proper choice?  YUM, tar. gz., rpm, and APT are the choices given.  Thank you.  GB

Answer (score 0):

**APT** is the proper one for Ubuntu systems.

IMO after selecting  `apt`, the corresponding package would be installed through software center.

Comment: I would not install Flash that way, use apt-get. See the link I gave as a duplicate.

Comment: just answered only to the OP's question _Which is the proper choice? YUM, tar. gz., rpm, and APT are the choices given._

Comment: Installing from the repositories is, IMO, a better option. IMO it is best to educate the OP how to use the repos rather then allowing them to search and install software from around the internet and those are not the only choices, they may be the only choices the OP is aware of, but as an experienced user there are better choices.

Comment: your link  will explain him about that.